# How can I get my image to pull through in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

My image isn't pulling through to the background of a div.

[here's the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfKxq.png)

```css
.page-header {
  background-image: url("../images/page-header-img.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  width:100% ; 
  height:250px;
  display:block;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1 /  span 12;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  background-position: top;
}
```

```html
 <div class="page-header">

  <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-header {
  background-image: url("./../../images/page-header-img.png");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  width:100% ; 
  height:250px;
  display:block;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1 /  span 12;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  background-position: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't seem to have worked though D:

Comment: you may need to have {display: grid} before you use {grid-colum}. So he needs to have another div outside this div.

Comment: it does :) has a container around the whole page - but thank you!

Comment: @chloea97 you use an scss file. Do you build and if yes where is your style.css? o.O

Comment: Yes i do use build! :)  My style.css is in the main MJC folder with all of the php files, could that be causing any problems? @ivollmer

Comment: Yes you need to go from the path where your style.css is. :D

Comment: Thank you :D how do it do that!?

Comment: @chloea97 When your style.css is in the mjc folder, ./images/page-header-img.png should do the trick

Comment: This hasn't seemed to work either, my npm run build is throwing a warning too

Comment: @chloea97 please join this room ^^ https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202562/question-58912402

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to leave becuase it still wouldn't work but could you try inviting me again (sorry!!)

Comment: You can just rejoin with this link chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202562/question-58912402

Comment: Sorry! i'm not ignoring you - it's jsut still not letting me write anything. Still says I don't have enough reputation points!